# Executing a C program from PHP

Tags: php, c, bash, shell

I am executing a C program i.e. '.exe' that is an executable file from PHP.

I have an interface with an HTML which calls a PHP file whenever I click a button.

On PHP, it calls up a shell script.
So on PHP, I use the following:

```
echo shell_exec('sh auto_script.sh');
```

The shell file executes the program .exe as follows:

```
./import -file.txt
```

where `import` is my executable C program .exe and file.txt is an input which I am hard coding as of now.

Executable file 'import' is stored in the same direcotry as php file called.

When I execute the shell script on a terminal, it executes properly with the necessary output.

But when I try to execute it from PHP it doesnt work. I have given full permissions to file as of now.

Comment: Does the script `cd` to the directory containing the `import` program? `./` means to find the program in the current working directory.

Comment: You need quotes around the argument to `shell_exec()`.

Comment: Yes the import is an executable which is in the same directory as php file and I do have quotes around the argument in shell_exec.

Comment: Add `2>&1` to the end of the argument to `shell_exec()` so you see any error messages.

Comment: If the script uses any bash extensions you should run it as `bash auto_script.sh`, not `sh auto_script.sh`.

Comment: @VivekEtte `./` looks in the current working directory, not the directory with the php file. Use absolute path. This also goes for `sh auto_script.sh`.

Comment: With 2>&1 , I was able to view the error "segmentation fault" , but when i execute the .exe file individually it does not throw any segmentation fault error.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on the [[ shell_exec ]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) manpage says `shell_exec` has the following definition :

> string shell_exec ( string $cmd )

which means that the argument should be a string, which indeed means it should be inside quotes. BTW, you don't need a mediator script here anyways, So do :

```
echo shell_exec('./import "-file.txt"'); //Using relative paths
```

Having said that placing the binary in the scripts folder is a bad idea, but I hope above helps you to get you going.

Comment: the C program is throwing a segmentaion fault error when I execute it via shell script but when I execute it individually it does not throw any error